# Word 2010 prints document properties

Tags: printing, word-2010

Everytime I print a page or a blank one, my printer prints 3 pages. The first page is:

```
Microsoft World - Document1
NWORD.EXE
  6:291:87
  27/2/4
```

The other 2 pages are blank. This has happened since a few days.

I already checked in Options->Display->PrintDocumentSettings and it's unchecked!

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the default template it is using.

The default template is named Normal.dotm in Word 2010

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates.
```

The AppData folder is hidden so you need to show hidden files and folders in Windows Explorer in order to see it.

1. Exit Word.
2. Move Normal.dotm to some other folder (save it somewhere else).
3. Restart Word - Document should be blank now.